# How can I produce $\sqrt{4+4t^2+t^4}=2+t^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sqrt{4+4t^2+t^4}=2+t^2$

That is the solution my calculator produces but I don't understand how it gets that solution.

If I factor it I get:

$\sqrt{4(1+t^2)+t^4} = 2\sqrt{1+t^2+t^4}$

$2\sqrt{1+t^2(1+t^2)}$

So how do I get from there to $2+t^2$

Comment: Try squaring $2+t^2$. Also, your $2\sqrt{1+t^2+t^4}$ is wrong: it should be $2\sqrt{1+t^2+\frac14t^4}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott As always, thank you for your help, sir.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{(t^4+4t^2+4)}=\sqrt{(t^2+2)^2}=2+t^2$

Comment: Ahh. this helped me to 'see' the factoring.  I didn't even notice that at first.

Comment: sometimes small things baffles us. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $(2+t^2)^2=4+4t^2+t^4$ then you can deduce your relation.

Answer (score -2):

You can factor it a different way. Factor the entire thing, not just the first two terms.